# Winform Main Control Too Large

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a Winform application which should occupy the entire screen, the target device having 1920x1080 resolution.
The main control window is defined as follows:

```
MaximumSize 1920, 1080
Size 1920, 1080
MinimumSize 1918, 1078
StartPosition CenterScreen
```

To fill the screen I have added the following to the _Load method:

```
 this.TopMost = true;
 this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
 this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
 this.Activate();
```

When I run the application the Control Window begins at the top left, as it should, but the rightmost 5th and the bottom 5th (approximately) of the form is off the screen.  The controls that should appear in the cut-off regions are at appropriate locations (e.g. a label at Location 1712, 551, which should be within the boundaries of a 1920x1080 screen).
Can anyone explain? If I knew why this is happening, I'm sure the solution would be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible your Windows installation is actually scaling the form. This can be done using the DPI settings (a cut-off of 1/5th sounds like a DPI setting of 125%), or by Windows 10 when it is self-adjusting.

The best thing to do is not rely on screen measurements to be correct. Instead, try to use as much panels that are capable of auto-sizing, like `TableLayoutPanel` and others. In that way you won't need to keep calculating, instead the framework will do that for you.

Comment: More specifically, in my lenovo/Windows8 laptop, there is a setting in Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display with a slider bar allowing one to "Change the size of all items". In case anyone should ever need to know.

Answer (score 3):

> I have added the following to the _Load method

Using the Load event handler is the problem.  You are changing the layout metrics of the window *after* it was created.  A window is maximized by giving it a negative location and a size that's larger than the screen by twice the border width.  So that the border isn't visible.

But your code changes FormBorderStyle and now that location and size is not correct anymore.  Since the window no longer has a border.  So the window is too large and part of the client area is off the screen.

You *must* move the FormBorderStyle assignment into the constructor of the form so the window is created with the correct border.  Setting the property with the designer is simplest.